# Putting a matrix in to sparse form in linear time using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to put a matrix in sparse form, and so far I'm looping through the rows and columns checking every element to see if it's non zero. However, this seems to be order n^2, where n is the number of non zero elements in the matrix. Is there a way to do this order n?

Here is my code

```
function a = inputMatrix(X)




[m,n] = size(X);


k=1;
for i=1:m


   for j=1:n


       if X(i,j)~=0
           X(i,j);




           a(1,k) = struct('row',i,'column',j,'data',X(i,j));




           k = k+1;




       end




   end


end
```

Here is my time testing

```
ri = zeros(250,250);
rj = zeros(250,250);
rk = zeros(100,100);








for i=1:10000
    ri(i) = randi([-10000,10000],1,1);
end
tic;
inputMatrix(ri);
time(1) = toc;




for i=1:5000
    rj(i) = randi([-10000,10000],1,1);
end


tic;
inputMatrix(rj);
time(2) = toc;








for i=1:1000
    rk(i) = randi([-10000,10000],1,1);
end


tic;
inputMatrix(rj);
time(3) = toc;
```

Results:

time = 1.8009    0.5619    0.5545
no. non zero entires = 10 000,   5000, 1000

The results suggest there is a non linear relationship, and not order N

Comment: Why is it order n^2? I'd say it's order N, where N is the number of _total_ entries (zero or nonzero) of the matrix

Comment: Do you know of any way to make this function order n ? where n is the number of non zero entries? I thinks perhaps you are right it is order N at the moment. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that can be done. You at least need to check all values to see if they are zero or not

Comment: I have edited the post to add the code @LuisMendo

Comment: As I said, your code is order N, where N (or m*n in your case) is the total number of entries in the matrix

Comment: I have done some time testing and it seems there is a non linear relatoinship and not order m*n.   @Luis Mendo

I have also plotted some graphs and they also suggest an order of n^2

Answer (score 2):

`find` gives you the indices of nonzero elements and `sparse` converts the matrix directly to a sparse matrix.

Comment: @user142756: I don't really understand your question. Basically `find` and `sparse` do the same, only in a very efficient and vectorized way.